# Python pathlib on Windows can't expand user

Tags: python, windows, pathlib

Expanding "~" using Pathlib gives the wrong path.

```python
from pathlib import Path

ex = Path('~/Documents')
print(ex.expanduser())
```

I'm expecting "C:\Users{username}\Documents", but instead get "C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\Documents". Is there something wrong with my windows config?

Answer (score 1):

"C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile" is the home directory for `SYSTEM` account. Are you running the script as serivce?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by as service, but the script is being run through gitlab-ci shell.

Comment: I don't know GitLab CI, but it looks like it's running under `SYSTEM` account by default.